# CSS - positioning footer

Tags: css

I've been stuck with a gap at the bottom of my footer: http://pactlegacy.com/site/overview.php

I really can't figure it out since it was just right, meeting the bottom of the window.  I recently changed the pages to PHP but I don't see how that would effect anything.

I'm still kind of new to CSS so I got the Firefox Web Developer tool to help me troubleshoot. But that's not showing any padding or margins that would give me the gap at the bottom.

I'm really not sure what I'm missing here.  Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.  My footer was in an include file which was editting in a different editor.  It saved the file as UTF-8 format while the main file was saved as ANSI.

Saving them both as ANSI format removed the gap.

Answer (score 1):

you have some whitespace characters before and after `<a href="#" id="totop">TOP</a>`
, removing them fixes the problem (I've checked it on Google Chrome dev tools)

EDIT:
to be more accurate, try to remove those lines from your code:

```
<!--////////////////// Load JS Files -->


<!-- JavaScript at the bottom for fast page loading -->
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I just tried that and it doesn't seem to have changed anything

Comment: I see that it didn't help, the gap is still present but as you can see [here](http://i50.tinypic.com/zlzu4g.png) it's some kind of a additional whitespace character bug